# list all the lines of an output that are not in the contents of another file

Tags: sed, grep, files

I have a directory of files. I want to check which of these files are not listed in the contents of another file, (`content.txt`).

`content.txt` contains the file names, but also contains some text before and after, so I am looking for a substring search.

Example:

```
$ ls
./file1 ./file2 ./file3

$ cat /some/path/content.txt
name: file2 (y)
age: file6 (z)
height: file9 (x)
```

I would expect the hypothetical script to return:

```
file1
file3
```

My current non-working solution is to use `find .` to list all the files, then use a sed replacement to replace the folder name, and then try to use grep to see if it is in the file:
`find . | sed 's|MyFolder/||' | xargs -I {} -0 grep {} /some/path/content.txt`

This seems inefficient, and I am not sure how to proceed further. I thought about using grep's `-qs` and checking the exit code from xargs, but that only results in one output rather than checking every single file.

`find . | sed 's|MyFolder/||' | (xargs -I {} -0 grep {} /some/path/content.txt) && echo "true" || echo "false"`

Comment: I don't understand why there's `file9` in the expected output. Did you mean `file3` instead like in `comm -23 <(ls) <(sort /some/path/content.txt)` ?

Comment: yes, it was a mistake, it should have been file3. your command works, but I also forgot to mention that the text won't be 1:1. It'll have some text before and after it, so `content.txt` won't have `file1` but more something like, `name: file1 (y)`

Comment: Do file names contain spaces or other characters that require quotes around them?

Comment: yes they have spaces & special characters

Comment: Why is `file1` in your expected output when it doesn't exist in `content.txt`?

Comment: If your real file names can contain "spaces & special characters" then show "spaces & special characters" in your example file names, otherwise you'll probably get a solution to a problem other than the one you really have.